# How to pass enum name to switch directly, vc++ mfc

Tags: c, visual-c++, enums, switch-statement

I am searching to know how to pass the enum name directly to switch case.
Eg:

```
enum Flower { rose, jasmine };

switch (Flower)
{
case rose : //Code for rose
case jasmine: //Code for jasmine
}
```

Someone please help me how to do this way? I found this code portions from C. But I need the same code portions in C++. Is it possible in c++? Please help me. Thanks all

Comment: `switch` statement takes an expression, not a type.

Comment: also, you might want to use C++11 `enum class` instead of regular C-enums

Comment: Do you mean `switch (rose)`? If you have `enum class Flower`, then `switch (Flower::rose)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++ Programmer,**switch(Expression)**,the Expression's result must be a integer value. enum Flower{rose,jasmine}; **Flower** is just a Type,not a value,
like int rose = 0,int jasmine=1,you can't use it in switch expression.
You can just define like **enum Flower fname**;

```
switch(fname)
{
   case rose:
    ...
   break;
   case jasmine:
    ...
   break;
   default:
   break;
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much..this was wat i was looking for. Got my program correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
Flower f = rose;
...
switch (f)
{
  case rose : //Code for rose
  case jasmine: //Code for jasmine
}
```